# Android with Kotlin: How to filter DatabaseReference

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to filter a getReference according to the data that is saved in a field.
I want it to return only the uid that have the "status" with a value of "1"
my code is this for now, it is returning all the uid that are inside "empleados"

```
override suspend fun getEmpleados(): DatabaseReference {
   return db.getReference("empleados")
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].